# Function to evaluate valid and invalid dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008

I receive data in a couple of formats. Dates are varchar(10)
For example:

1> 951116 = YYMMDD

2> 122487 = MMDDYY

There exists rows with blank values or some rows have some text in it.

I want to check if it is a date and convert it, else it can be null.

I have been using the following code but it only enables me to convert the date as in the 1st example and throws an error in the second one.

```
create view v2 as 
SELECT name 
  ,CASE WHEN LEN(DOB) < 6 THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, 
                  CAST(CAST('19' + SUBSTRING(DOB, 5, 2) + SUBSTRING(DOB, 1, 2) + SUBSTRING(DOB, 3, 2) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS DATE), 110) END AS OWNR_DOB
FROM customer
```

I want to write a function and get it to YYYYMMDD format.

A simple function just to convert the YYMMDD format to YYYYMMDD and treat the other values as invalid or null can be a start too.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What date would this string be?    "101112"

Comment: Do you have a column that identifies whether the date falls under type 1 or type 2? If thats the case then you can change the formula depending on the type.

Comment: That is one of the issue. There is no fixed format for the data I have with me. Is there anyway to get it to a fixed format and then convert the date to a Date time format?

Comment: No, SQL cannot be programmed to read the minds of the data entry personnel.

Comment: There is __no__ way of standarazing a fixed format column into one format if there is no information about which format does apply for each value. Which values would you filter to convert from YYMMDD to YYYYMMDD if you don't know to which value does this format apply to?

Comment: It's too bad you're on SQL 2008 - it seems like you're describing the functionality of `TRY_PARSE()` introduced in SQL 2012.

Comment: @akshaybhat Ask the person that gave you the dates to fix it to 1 format, or else some of those dates are useless

Comment: Thank you everyone. I had the same thought but just wanted to check if there was some way which I didn't know of to get this done.